# How to display JPanel per menu item in Swing?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jmenuitem

How to display panels based on selecting menu item from the menu bar,  like Netbeans IDE window?

if there is a simple way of doing things I appreciate it if someone helps me point in the right direction thanks.

Comment: spend some time on studying Swing API.

Answer (score 4):

> point in the right direction

It's better explained under *Swing Tutorial* on [How to Use Menus](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html) where you will find lots of detail examples along with snapshot.

You can use [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) to use same space for multiple views.

**Hint:** Just switch between multiple `JPanel` when any `JMenuItem` is selected/clicked.

Read more about [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)